# Insert if last row's field meets clause or sub query result is equal to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a single insert that applies the following

```
______________________________
| id | item (fk) | condition |
| 1  | 3         | NEW       |
| 2  | 3         | USED      |
| 3  | 2         | USED      |
______________________________
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

Given an item id = 3 for example, I would like to insert a new rows in this table if one of these two conditions are met:

1. the row with the largest id is not "NEW"`
2. the `count` of entries of this item (id = 3) is `equal to 0`

The closest I got so far was:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (item, condition)
        SELECT (itemId, "NEW")  FROM ( 
                    SELECT condition, count(*) as rowCount
                    FROM tableA 
                    WHERE item = itemId 
                    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) a
            WHERE a.condition <> "NEW" OR a.rowCount = 0;
```

But the count(*) messes up with the ordering.. Any clue?

Comment: How could the count be 0 if the id is already in the table?

Comment: The id does not necessarily exist in this table. The `itemId` is a value I am passing as a search criteria so it might or might not exist. If it doesn't it will return `(null, 0)` from `SELECT condition, count(*) as rowCount`, at the moment. But if more than 1 record exists, with different `condition` the order is not maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery that gets the row with the largest ID for that `item`:

```
SELECT condition
FROM tableA
WHERE item = 3
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If there are no rows for this `item`, this subquery will return `NULL`. You can use the null-safe equality operator to handle this.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (item, condition)
SELECT 3, "NEW"
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT (
    SELECT condition
    FROM tableA
    WHERE item = 3
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) <=> "NEW"
```

Comment: good one, it runs much faster.. just added a `<=> "NEW" AND item = 3 LIMIT 1;` and it returns a single result if it meets the condition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. `item = 3` should be in the subquery, not the main query.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking about this as an aggregation subquery with no `GROUP BY`.  This always returns exactly one row, so you will still have a row even if `cnt` is `0`:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (item, condition)
    SELECT a.itemId, a.condition
    FROM (SELECT @itemId as itemId, 'NEW' as condition,
                 COUNT(*) as cnt,
                 MAX(id) as max_id,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN condition = 'NEW' THEN id END) as max_new
          FROM tableA
          WHERE item = @itemId
         ) a
    WHERE cnt = 0 OR max_new is null or max_new < max_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your answer effectively makes sense but in my qa database it takes a bit long (4.5 sec). This query runs approximately 1 million times a day so I will see what I can do from there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bobleujr . . . If performance is a concern, then you need filtering in the subquery.